# Intercom System

Tags: amplifier, speakers, microphone

I am trying to make a prototype to test a circuit.

It is about am intercom circuit.

I have an intercom device with 2 wires, and it supports multiple stations and everybody can talk and hear at the same time.

I just want to upgrade this board.

The main aims are:

1. When we want to talk we must talk very very close to the microphone. I want to talk from 1 or 2 meters away.
2. The speaker output is not enough to hear from 2 meters so I want to hear voice from 2 meters.

I tried a few things.

First I look microphone pin with an oscilloscope and I use a microphone amplifier board (LM393)and I see this board added a DC offset to the signal.

Another thing I have tried is using a speaker amplifier TDA2030 module. When I talked into the microphone very close the voice is high. But when I am far away from the microphone I can hear voice when I am really close to the speaker.

Also, I used a TDA8932 speaker amplifier module. It wants input as a differential audio input (2 pins,) but this module has one output pin. When I connect microphone module out pin to TDA8932 input pin(+) it makes very big noises.

I tried to connect other pin to GND. It didn't work. When module wants 2 audio input pin How can I connect one microphonr module output pin?

My questions:

1. For microphone topics if I want to talk from 2 meters away which module I can use? Can I use a mic amplifier module to make this aim?
2. For the speaker is it okay to take main board's speaker output to speaker module input's pin and make voice louder?

I can make tests and add an oscilloscope photo with your recommendations.

Modules:

- [TDA8932](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01463BK8C)
- [LM393 microphone module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S4DTKYH)
- [TDA2030](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FDD3OCO)

Comment: *everybody can talk and hear at the same time* - How are you going to prevent acoustic feedback when you put in the amplifiers?

Comment: You're trying to convert an ordinary telephone into a [speakerphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speakerphone), which requires an [adaptive echo canceller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_suppression_and_cancellation).

Comment: Your microphone module is not an audio amplifier.  It is a sound detector that has a digital output when detects loud noises.  It also has an output that comes directly from its built in microphone.  The microphone output is **not** amplified.

Comment: Yes with this Mic Module when I look with oscilloscope I see this module just add a DC offset voltage with max 200mV. I also have Max9814 mic Module. It is what I need ?